# Programmatically set or leave iOS Guided Access with Xamarin.iOS

Tags: c#, ios, iphone, xamarin, xamarin.ios

I developed an app for an enterprise environment. The iOS devices are locked in **Guided Access** by a MDM solution, i.e. the devices are supervised. Setting or leaving the Guided Access from the MDM solution works fine. But I also need a way to leave the Guided Access manually and reactivate it later. I've tried it with **Xamarin.iOS 9.0.1.25**, **iOS 9.1** and the ***"RequestGuidedAccessSession"*** method, but every time my app **crashes(!)** at this function call. What's wrong with my code or is this function missing in Xamarin.iOS? Thanks in advance!

```
partial void onLockButtonClicked(Foundation.NSObject sender)
{
    try
    {
        UIKit.UIAccessibility.RequestGuidedAccessSession(true, (a) => {
            if (a)
            {
                System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Locked -> true");
            }
            else
            {
                System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Locked -> false");
            }
        });
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(ex.Message);
    }
}
```

Comment: If you are still active here: have you found any solution for this problem?